# Perform function at certain clock time

Tags: c++, clock

I would like the user to input a time e.g. 1400h - which will then cause a function to run at 1400h.

How can I do this?

Context: I have a client-server program that works on the same computer - and I need several nodes to send messages simultaneously (which is the function as above)

edit: I do not want to use a `sleep()` function, ideally, as the issue is that the clients will be started at different times and it is much neater as a solution to call something that causes the function to execute at 1400h.

Comment: I am sure there are more then enough cron modules for C++. Try using one of them.

Comment: You need to call sleep() in some form, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until), e.g.

```
void main()
{
     auto fire_time = /**/;

     std::thread thread([&]
     {
          std::this_thread::sleep_until(fire_time);
          fire();
     });
     thread.join();       
}
```

You can refactor that into a helper function, which is probably what you are looking for:

```
template<class Func, class Clock, class Duration>
void run_at(Func&& func, const std::chrono::time_point<Clock,Duration>& sleep_time)
{
    std::thread(std::bind([&](const Func& func)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(sleep_time);
        func();
    }, std::move(func)))
    .detach();
}
```

Comment: how would I use this - I have multiple threads running in the program (and I'm pretty new to using threads!). I can isolate the function I want to call into a separate thread, but how do I call `sleep_until()` on a specific thread?

Comment: does't, "std::this_thread::sleep_until" kind of answer your question? It will sleep on the "this" thread, i.e. the thread calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

If the program is running the entire time, use a function such as `sleep` to wait the amount of time between now and 1400h. You might need to do this in a separate thread to allow the program to do other things, or replace the `sleep` with an event loop timeout (if the program is event-loop-based).

If the program must exit, then you must use a system facility, such as `at` on Unix, to arrange the program to be restarted and code to be executed at the specified time.

Comment: I don't want to use a `sleep(x)` as the clients will be started at different times - but I want them to fire at the same time. I'll update this in the question!

Comment: @sccs Exactly, and this is why `x` in `sleep(x)` must be the *amount of time between now and 1400h*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a some kind of task manager. That's a basic model. Breeding sleeping threads is very wrong way to do that job. A single manager will know when to run a next task. How to run a task is another question. You can make new thread per task if you want them to be interactive. Or you can serialize them and run from within the manager thread.