# Inputs to sleep_until()

Tags: c++, sleep

As per an answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563412/perform-function-at-certain-clock-time/17565485?noredirect=1#17565485), I am trying to use `sleep_until()` but cannot find a tutorial that tells me how to use it with an actual time such as 1400:00h.

There are examples like this: `std::this_thread::sleep_until(system_clock::now() + seconds(10));`, but I would like something that actually lets me specify a clock time. What format should this be in? I would appreciate any examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To wait until a specified clock time, you need to get a `time_t` that represents that clock time, and then use [`std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t`](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t.html) to create a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` which you can then use with the xxx_until functions such as `std::this_thread::sleep_until`.

e.g.

```
void foo(){
    tm timeout_tm={0};
    // set timeout_tm to 14:00:01 today
    timeout_tm.tm_year = 2013 - 1900;
    timeout_tm.tm_mon = 7 - 1;
    timeout_tm.tm_mday = 10;
    timeout_tm.tm_hour = 14;
    timeout_tm.tm_min = 0;
    timeout_tm.tm_sec = 1;
    timeout_tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    time_t timeout_time_t=mktime(&timeout_tm);
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timeout_tp=
        std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(timeout_time_t);
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(timeout_tp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [`std::chrono`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/)

There are all sorts of date/time representation formats you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/?kw=mktime) to make up a time specification which you can use in sleep_until as done [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_until/?kw=sleep_until)